# Power BI: Text as MMM/YYYY to Date format MM/DD/YYYY

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource, powerbi-custom-visuals

I'm having issues with a data set, where the original data is stored as text and it needs to display as a date format so it can graph how I'd like.

Below is an example of what I have and what I'd like it to look like.

I'm really lost on how to do it, any help is appreciated.

| Original | Desired |
| --- | --- |
| 001/2023 | 1/1/2023 |
| 002/2024 | 2/1/2024 |

I've tried date format changes and adding custom columns to make it a date format but it keeps giving me "error" for all of my values. My guess this is because the original is not set up with a date.

Answer (score 1):

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMjAw1DcyMDJWitUBcYxAHBOl2FgA", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [#"Sütun 1" = _t]),
    #"Inserted Text Range" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Text Range", each Text.Middle([Sütun 1], 0, 1), type text),
    #"Inserted Text Range1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted Text Range", "Text Range.1", each Text.Middle([Sütun 1], 1, 2), type text),
    #"Inserted Text Range2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted Text Range1", "Text Range.2", each Text.Middle([Sütun 1], 4, 4), type text),
    #"Inserted Merged Column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted Text Range2", "Merged", each Text.Combine({[Text Range.1], [Text Range], [Text Range.2]}, "/"), type text),
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Inserted Merged Column","0","1",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Text Range"})
in
    #"Replaced Value"
```

We can provide the output you want with this query.

Comment: where does this get inserted? as a custom column or as a query? I tried the custom column option and the value i get is "Table" for everything.

Comment: writing in the advanced regulatory field